# FireDAC SQL Server Connection: Untrusted certificate

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ssl, anydac, firedac

I enabled secure connection by choosing a self-signed certificate on my SQL Server.

I can connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio and adding `TrustServerCertificate=True` into `Additional Connection Parameters`.

I need same configuration for FireDAC connection because it gives similar error

> SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

when I try connecting.

How to tell this to FireDAC? (Delphi XE4, FireDAC: 8)

PS: I've already added my self-signed certificate into windows "Trusted Root Certification Authorities", but it seems that FireDAC ignores it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `ODBCAdvanced=TrustServerCertificate=yes` to your connection definition parameters. Also verify, that you have SQL Server Native Client installed. Read more:

- [TrustServerCertificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx) ODBC connection parameter;
- FireDAC [SQL Server connectivity](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/Connect_to_Microsoft_SQL_Server.html).

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem for run-time. I've added 'TrustServerCertificate=yes' into ODBCAdvanced property of TADPhysMSSQLDriverLink. But if I make ADConnection.connected=true on design-time, I get another error says that "SSL Provider: The target principal name is incorrect". As a result, run-time connection is ok, but design-time connection still has problem. Any suggestion for it?

Comment: I use tunneling for the SQL connection over proxy. (From Indy, TidMappedPortTCP works great on it). I'll try another pc which has direct internet connection and see if same error is available.

Comment: You should add `ODBCAdvanced=...` to TADConnection.Params or to your persistent connection definition parameters.